# Should a married woman cover her hair in the succah?

Tags: halacha, women, sukkah, home-house, hair-covering

For women who do not cover their hair while in their own homes, should they cover it while in their own succah? (I.e. does the succah classify as the home for this purpose?)

Would it make a difference where the succah is? For example, one that's clearly outside; one that is flush against the door; or one that is actually indoors (such as via retractable roof).

Comment: Does the Sukkah have see through walls?

Comment: @DoubleAA Would that make a difference? See through walls don't matter in someone else's house.

Comment: "See through walls don't matter in someone else's house." I don't know what case you are thinking of. Would you go to a bathroom with see through walls?

Comment: I don't see what see through walls have to do with hair covering.

Comment: Does she cover her hair in her back yard?

Comment: @WAF My mother does. That's why i differentiated between the location of the succah.

Comment: תשבו כעין תדורו

Comment: Why do you think she might have to cover her hair? Does she cover her hair in a hotel room? In a public bathroom stall? You can (and should) sleep (that includes having Biah) in a Sukkah. Must she cover her hair for those activities?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think i say in the question that it probably hinges on how much of a home the succah is.

Comment: I guess I fail to see any remotely reasonable explanation for why it wouldn't be sufficiently her home. Perhaps you can elaborate why it might not be sufficiently a home.

Comment: @DoubleAA Most people (nowadays) don't really *live* in the succah.

Comment: I don't know what you mean? Are you measuring in hours spent in the Sukkah? But then how many hours do you spend in your laundry room/closet/boiler-room/attic?

Comment: @DoubleAA Simply how they perceive it.

Comment: Perhaps limit your question to those who don't perceive their Sukkah's as part of their home? I'm rather skeptical how big that category is anyway. IAE finding some way to [edit] to clarify your motivation (so others don't have to dredge through these comments) is always good.